# heroku S3 pre-signed post and S3 request signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a direct upload from my iOS app to S3 using a [pre-signed post from heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python).  Heroku returns the following to my swift app:

`{'url': u'https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/filename', 'data': {'url': u'https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/', 'fields': {'Content-Type': 'm4a', 'key': u'filename', 'AWSAccessKeyId': u'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'acl': 'public-read', 'policy': u'wtLepKMeghI3rt1UeikLoQcNTYtMDktMTBUMTc6NDE6MTJaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJhY2wiOiAicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSwgeyJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiOiAibTRhIn0sIHsiYnVja2V0IjogImZ1eZEaJKYzeDgZwz3lOPtys5B0MigIwImv2OpQm3ylP==', 'signature': u'qr647bMEA9M8LeBVqkJLcvEIO4g='}}}`

As you can see, there is a signature which is: `qr647bMEA9M8LeBVqkJLcvEIO4g=`

and a policy

`wtLepKMeghI3rt1UeikLoQcNTYtMDktMTBUMTc6NDE6MTJaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJhY2wiOiAicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSwgeyJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiOiAibTRhIn0sIHsiYnVja2V0IjogImZ1eZEaJKYzeDgZwz3lOPtys5B0MigIwImv2OpQm3ylP==`

In the AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html), the signature example they use (below) has a lot more characters than the signature that is returned from Heroku

`Signature=5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7`

Is the signature provided by heroku different than what amazon is asking for to sign a request?  Am I not suppose to use the signature that is returned from Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7` is in hexadecimal and `qr647bMEA9M8LeBVqkJLcvEIO4g=` is in base64 encoding and is much shorter than hex since `base64` uses 64 chars for encoding while `hex` uses 16 chars.

AWS expects the signature in base64 encoding. So what Heroku returns to you is correct. What problems are you having?

Comment: I'm trying to make a signed request to S3 for the first time and I'm unable to make a connection so I decided to look at the documentation to see if I'm doing anything wrong.  I'm currently getting a http error code 400.  Not sure if I'm providing the required values in the correct format.

Comment: 400 can mean anything. The response should have more information on why it is returning 400.